# Mongodb retrieve array fields in the document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This my collection:

```
{
    "Id" : "4",
    "tType" : "77",
    "tId" : "001",
    "variables" : [ 
        {
            "controller" : 4444,
            "mod" : 41,
            "var" : "41",
            "Type" : 4,
            "vType" : "DI",
            "duration" : "",

            "Data" : [ 
                {
                    "Time" : 1483209000,
                    "value" : 50
                }, 
                {
                    "Time" : 1483209000,
                    "value" : 50
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "controller" : 1,
            "mod" : 1,
            "var" : "1",
            "Type" : 11,
            "vType" : "AO",
            "duration" : "",

            "Data" : [ 
                {
                    "Time" : 1483209000,
                    "value" : 30
                }, 
                {
                    "Time" : 1483209000,
                    "value" : 30
                } 

            ]
        } 

    ]
}
```

This was i tried:

```
db.app.aggregate([
{"$match":{
    "variables.controller":4444,
      "variables.mod":41,
      "variables.var":"41"
    }
    },
    {"$project":{
        "_id":0,
        "variables.Data.Time":1,
        "variables.Data.value":1
        }
        }
])
```

In my collection i need to get first set off Data array fields only,based on filter condition variables array controller,tType fields, but in my above aggregate query it retrieve all variables arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
db.app.aggregate([ {$match:{
"variables.controller":4444,
  "variables.mod":41,
  "variables.var":"41"
}}, {$project:{data:"$variables.Data", _id:0}},{$unwind:"$data"},{$unwind:"$data"},{$limit:1} ]).pretty()
```